# Discord.js - How can you make a bot print the name of a server through the server ID?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a command that when kicked/banned from a server, it DM's you `"You've been kicked from [SERVERNAME]:"`, but I am unsure how to make it print the name of the server, along with the server icon.

Would someone be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Client#guildBanAdd

The following event, according to the [documents](https://discord.js.org/#/docs), returns two parameters:

- Guild: The guild the spoken of ban occurred from.
- User: The user who was banned.

We can take this knowledge and use it in the purpose of DMing the banned user with the guild's name, and using the icon as well.

```
client.on('guildBanAdd', (guild, user) => {
  user.send(`You were banned from ${guild.name}!`, {
    files: [guild.iconURL()]
  })
})
```

Comment: When attempting to use the code listed above, it returned with `"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user"`

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility where the user does not accept direct messages from members he does not share a guild with, resulting in said error. Unfortunately, bots cannot bypass this feature, and your only result would be to catch the error and console log that sending the message failed due to the user not allowing direct messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the guild's name via `<Guild>.name`. If you have only the guild ID, you can get the Guild with `<Client>.guilds.cache.get(id)`.